# why is my "left join on" is throwing "unexpected token: on" error?

Tags: sql, hibernate, ejb

I have two queries to run:

```
2012-08-07 11:24:02,561 ERROR [org.hibernate.hql.PARSER] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-12) line 1:105: unexpected token: ON
2012-08-07 11:24:02,686 ERROR [org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-12) javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ON near line 1, column 105 
[SELECT count(o) from ejb.entity.News o LEFT JOIN NewsNewsDistributionServiceLink p ON o.id = p.newsId WHERE o.statusId = ?1 AND p.newsDistServiceCode is ?2]

2012-08-07 11:26:15,605 ERROR [org.hibernate.hql.PARSER] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-12) line 1:105: unexpected token: ON
2012-08-07 11:26:15,609 ERROR [org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-12) javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ON near line 1, column 105 
[SELECT count(o) from entity.News o LEFT JOIN NewsNewsDistributionServiceLink p ON o.id = p.newsId WHERE o.companyId = ?1 AND o.statusId = ?2 AND p.newsDistServiceCode is ?3]
```

I ran the following in SQuirreL SQL client:

```
select * from news n left join news_news_distribution_service_link nl
on n.id=nl.news_id
where news_distribution_service_code is null
```

This will return results, but when I translate this for my java servlet, it throws that error.

News table:

```
id -PK
company_id
user_id
title
type_id
status_id
location
is_immediate
contents
created_date
last_modified_date
release_date
delete_date
corrected_news_id
can_distribute
was_distributed
```

NewsNewsDistLink table:

```
id -PK 
news_id - this is equal to the id in News
news_distribution_service_code
```

Code:

```
String _query = "SELECT COUNT(o) FROM News o " + (filter.tierGroup != null ? TIER_GROUP_JOIN : "") + "WHERE ";
            WhereClauseBuilder builder = getWhereClause(filter);
            _query+= builder.where.toString();

            Query query = em.createQuery(_query);
            query.setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", true);
            builder.bind(query);
```

The whereClauseBuilder() basically adds params after "where", the bind() basically binds the param with ?# and its values. Lastly p.newsDistServiceCode will most likely be null most of the time(>95%).

Comment: Post your Java and Hibernate code

Comment: Instead of COUNT(o) did you try COUNT(*)?

Comment: @contactmatt count(*) will not work in hibernate(?), i believe it threw an error, it should have said count(o.id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the queries are not SQL queries, but HQL queries. SQL and HQL are two different languages. SQL works on tables and columns, whereas HQL works on Hibernate entities and associations.

See the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql).